# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: null when passing an arg to a spark-submit job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, url

I have a small spark scala job which takes in a few args, namely **http_endpoint**

```
import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpOptions}

1 object Main extends App {
2
3   val master = args(0)
4   val http_endpoint = args(1)
5   ...
6   ...
7   
8   def sendRequest = ( text: String ) => {
9      println("#####################: " + http_endpoint)
10     val result = Http(http_endpoint)
11    ...
12    ...
13  }
```

I then send this as a spark-submit job to yarn.

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
my-job-example-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
yarn \
"http://my-url-example-12311.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/my/app"
```

Error:

```
#####################: null
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: null
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:611)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:508)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:457)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:343)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.asString(Http.scala:492)
```

I have even used speech quotation marks around the URL i send, but it fails. When I hardcode this in the code in **line number 10** it works. Any idea how I can still get it working when passed as an arg?

Comment: tried but failed with same error...

Comment: Could you check by printing `master`,`http_endpoint` to see are you able to get the values?

Comment: prints null, have updated my question

Comment: I have tested below code in **local/yarn-client/yarn-cluster** modes and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with passing arguments using `--conf spark.driver.args="<args>"`

- In your code use `spark.sparkContext.getConf.get()` to get the arguments.

---

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.driver.args="yarn http://my-url-example-12311.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/my/app" my-job-example-assembly-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**`Example:`**

```
spark-shell --conf spark.driver.args="yarn http://my-url-example-12311.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/my/app"

val arg0=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")(0)
//String = yarn
val arg1=spark.sparkContext.getConf.get("spark.driver.args").split("\\s+")(1)
//String = http://my-url-example-12311.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/my/app
```